# How to display two images on one line Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hello i m new to bootstrap and i want to know how to display two images on one line and keep the responsive function.Can you give me an example ?

```
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">
<img src="images/l.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Logo">
 </div>
```

Comment: where is your css source code??

Comment: I cannot see two images in your HTML ?

Comment: If you find any of the answer correct please mark them as correct :) There should be a check mark there hehe

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Sure, for BS2:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span6"><img src="yourimage"/></div>
    <div class="span6"><img src="yourimage"/></div>
</div>
```

For BS3:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6"><img src="yourimage"/></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6"><img src="yourimage"/></div>
</div>
```

**EDIT: 01/03/2017**
For BS4 (w/ FLEXBOX):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col"><img src="yourimage"/></div>
    <div class="col"><img src="yourimage"/></div>
</div>
```

Another solution is to float the images to the left:

```
<img class="pull-left" src="yourimage"/>
<img class="pull-left" src="yourimage"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be something like that

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">
  <img src="images/l.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Logo">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">
  <img src="images/2.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Logo">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">
  <img src="images/2.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Logo">
  </div>

 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have anather question i want a 3-rd element in the right (image)?